# Unable to open any save games after patch

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I just loaded up Minecraft (on Xbox), and it updated with the latest version (Yay new stuff!).

However, after it restarted, I was unable to open any existing save files.

Is there some way around this, or is this one of the new *features*?

**UPDATE**: I am also unable to reopen and new save files (created after the update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some players not being able to load saves is a [known bug in Title Update 9](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_version_history#1.4) (TU9):

> Xbox Live Silver Members sometimes may not be able to load old saves.

TU9 is riddled with show-stopping bugs, and TU10 is apparently under feverish development to fix the fiasco TU9 is causing.

The only free, permanent solution is to wait for the update. The more immediate solution is to pay for a Gold membership. A temporary work-around is to disconnect your Xbox's Internet (either unplugging the cable, or turning off your wireless router) before starting Minecraft and loading your world, then reconnecting/turning it back on after your world is loaded.

Comment: Not true. There is a workaround. Turn your wireless router off or unplug the ethernet from the xbox prior to launching minecraft. You will be warned about not being able to connect to xbox live. Say ok, load a game. Then turn the router back on/plug in the ethernet. You should be good to go. Don't pay for a Gold Membership if you don't need it.